# Using BIND for virtual hosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, bind, hosts, virtualhost

I've created the following virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  testingsitehere.com
              ServerAlias  www.testingsitehere.com 
    DocumentRoot /www/vhosts/testingsitehere.com
    ErrorLog /www/Apache22/logs/error.log

    <Directory "/www/vhosts/testingsitehere.com">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and have installed BIND.

This is a testing server, not public-facing, so no one can access these.
It uses Web-Developer Server Suite (hence the C:/www/vhosts folder path).

Should I use BIND over HOSTS file to map my domains to localhost, or should I keep using HOSTS as I did before?

Can BIND actually map domains/DNS to localhost, 127.0.0.1 or have I misunderstood here?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you are not serving a local network/intranet, there's no need to setup BIND, I'd say. If you are testing your virtual host from the same machine that it is running on, using `%systemroot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` will work just fine.

What additional mapping apart from `testingsitehere.com` to 127.0.0.1 were you thinking of?